# Spring boot 3 logging dependency conflict

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, logback, slf4j

We're in the process of upgrading to spring boot 3 in our application at the moment and we're getting some issues at runtime with logger factories clashing.

We use logback for our logging implementation, but via slf4j.

We're pulling in the `spring-boot-starter-logging` module, and not specifying our own versions of slf4j or logback in our build.gradle.

It's a really complicated project with lots of dependencies, but the logging dependencies are all here:

```
integrationTestRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'integration test'.
+--- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.6
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.0 -> 2.14.2
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.14.2
|         |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.14.2
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.14.2 (c)
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.14.2 (c)
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.2 (c)
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-guava:2.14.2 (c)
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.14.2 (c)
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.14.2 (c)
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:2.14.2 (c)
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.14.2 (c)
|         |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.14.2 (c)
|         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.14.2
|         |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.14.2 (*)
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.14.2 (*)
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging -> 3.0.5
|    \--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.6
|         +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.4.6
|         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.4 -> 2.0.7
+--- org.springframework:spring-context -> 6.0.7
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:6.0.7
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:6.0.7
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.0.7
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:6.0.7
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.0.7 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:6.0.7 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.0.7 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:6.0.7
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.0.7 (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-beans -> 6.0.7 (*)
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:{strictly 2.14.2} -> 2.14.2 (*)
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:{strictly 2.14.2} -> 2.14.2 (*)
+--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:9.0.69
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:9.0.69 -> 10.1.7
+--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 -> 1.2
```

We apply the following exclusions and dependencies to all modules in the multimodule build:

```
    configurations.all {
        // Short version cache so we don't accidentally use old versions
        resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 10, 'minutes'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-to-slf4j'
        exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-api'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'jul-to-slf4j'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation 'net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.6'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging'
```

Running my integration tests gives me:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.helpers.SubstituteLoggerFactory loaded from file: .../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.7/41eb7184ea9d556f23e18b5cb99cad1f8581fc00/slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.helpers.SubstituteLoggerFactory
```

Strangely, this is only effecting some of the integration tests. Others are running as expected.

I'm at a bit of a loss here. I can't exclude logback or slf4j, as both of them are required. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT** I've done some debugging this morning and what seems to be happening is that whilst the `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` is being initialised, it returns the substitute logger.

Comment: You shouldn't need `spring-boot-starter-logging` as that is included by default. Please add your dependencies to the question.

Comment: I'm going to struggle to include all of my dependencies to be honest. It's a pretty huge list. I'll see if I can replicate in a sample project.

Comment: @M.Deinum i've added some more dependencies & global exclude details

Comment: The `logstash-logback-encoder` you included is for Logback 1.2 which is SLF4J 1.7.  I also wonder why `commons-logging` is on the classpath, that shouldn't be there. Finally you included an incompatible version of `org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core` (version 9, whereas Spring BOot 3 needs version 10).

Comment: I am experiencing this exact problem as well after migrating to spring boot 3.0.5. i.e. Same exception. During tests. Some tests run and others fail.

Comment: I've added an edit explaining what I think is happening. I'm still not totally sure why it's happening, but that seems to be what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've got to the bottom of our issue here. Here's a summary of what was going on:

- In the `LoggerFactory`, we could see that SLF4J was finding Logback as the provider, and started initialising it.
- That initialisation took up to a second in some cases.
- The reason the initialisation took a while was because it was using our main application `logback.xml` and apparently initialising the `logstash` appender is a fairly slow process.

The root cause of the problem seems to be that whilst slf4j is initialising, any requests to the `LoggerFactory#getProvider` method return the substitute provider, at which point the `LogbackLoggingSystem#getLoggerContext` in spring boot throws an exception, as the `LoggerFactory` returned is not valid.

I'm going to raise a bug against slf4j for this behaviour. It feels to me that if it's initialising, it shouldn't just return a dummy implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing this problem. For me solution is to change logback to 1.4.7:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

And override version of SLF4J that is included in spring to

```
<slf4j.version>2.0.12</slf4j.version>
```

Actually I'm using spring-boot-starter-parent 3.2.2

Hope that helps.